# modify a value of a user control property from another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following user control

```
public partial class LayoutWindow : UserControl
{
 ....
}
```

on this user-control I have a button to open an another window call `PopUp`.

So I'm trying to update `LayoutWindow` UserControl `diagram.Bounds` property(which is canvas size), once button(`OkButton_Click`) click inside `PopUp` Window

So I tried following thing

```
 public partial class PopUp : Window
 {
    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          

          LayoutWindow lw= new LayoutWindow();
          lw.InitializeComponent();
          lw.diagram.Bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
          Close();
    }
}
```

but in this way it's not updating above propery, how can I do this properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the `LayoutWindow` in the `PopUp` window. You need to access the already existing instance. The easiest way to do this would probably be to inject the `PopUp` window with an instance of `LayoutWindow` when you create it:

```
public partial class PopUp : Window
{
    private readonly LayoutWindow _lw;
    public PopUp(LayoutWindow lw)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _lw = lw;
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _lw.diagram.Bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        Close();
    }
}
```

**LayoutWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
var popup = new PopUp(this);
popup.Show();
```

Comment: thnks I'll apply this and let u know.